# Compile 32bit binary for ARM

Tags: android, linux, cross-compiling, 32-bit

I have a Linux system and an old Nexus 4 phone. I am trying to compile a C application to run on it. Normally, when I compile C applications for other phones, I can simply use

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -static main.c
```

However, the Nexus 4 is old and does not support 64-bit executables

```
/system/bin/sh: /data/local/tmp/a.out: not executable: 64-bit ELF file
```

How can I compile a 32 bit application? The compiler does not regognize the -m32 flag

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-m32'
```

I also tried compiling my own cross-compiler using ct-ng, and explicitly enable there 32-bit support, but it did not help.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I think you need `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` package.

Comment: thanks! but it does not seem to make any difference

Comment: How did you "explicitly enable there 32-bit support"? Can you try '-mabi=ilp32' to see if it works?